# For the power series, what is the convergent region and how to find its value?

Tags: sequences-and-series

The power series given by

\begin{equation} \begin{split} &S(\alpha,n,x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_kx^k,\quad n\in \pmb{N},\quad 0<\alpha<2\\ 
&a_k=\left[ \alpha k+\alpha \atop n \right] = \frac{(\alpha k+\alpha)(\alpha k+\alpha +1)\cdots (\alpha k+\alpha +n-1)}{n!} \end{split} \end{equation}

To find its convergence region, I tried 
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{a_k}{a_{k-1}}&=\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac{(\alpha k+\alpha)(\alpha k+\alpha +1)\cdots (\alpha k+\alpha +n-1)}{(\alpha k)(\alpha k +1)\cdots (\alpha k +n-1)}\\
&=\lim_{k\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{k})(1+\frac{\alpha}{\alpha k+1})\cdots(1+\frac{\alpha}{\alpha k+n-1})\\
&=1
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Thus, I conclude that it converges when $|x|<1$. However, I find it's hard to test its convergence at $x=\pm 1$. I haven't find a way to deal with it.

Besides, for fixed values of $\alpha$ and $n$, to find an closed form expression to the sum   is even beyond my knowledge. I even don't know where to start.

Another more challenging problem for me is to obtain the value of

\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty [S(\alpha,n,x)]^2
\end{equation}

Can you give some reference on the above questions?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried the ratio test?

Comment: Yes. I have added in the post